# Why is my python code converting a 2-D array (matrix) to a 3-D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, covariance

I m not sure how or why, but my python code is converting the matrix I enter to a 3-D array. 
I simply want to find the covariance of a matrix (or a within-class scatter matrix) using this code :

```
enter code here
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats.stats as sss
class1 = np.loadtxt('class.txt')
col = np.loadtxt('col.txt')
print(class1)
idx = np.where(class1==1)
print(idx) 
Nin = col[idx,:]
print(Nin) 
idx2 = np.where(class1==0)
Nac= col[idx2,:]
NacT = np.transpose(Nac)
Scatter = np.dot(NacT,Nac)
ScatterAC = np.divide(Scatter) 

enter code here
```

The error I get is:

```
ValueError: shapes (739,8903,1) and (1,8903,739) not aligned: 1 (dim 2) != 8903 (dim 1)
```

I am not sure what is the problem? Can someone help?

Comment: With those `loadtxt` I can't replicate your data.  You don't even tell us the array shapes, or anything you deduced from the `print`.  From the error message I deduce `Nac` is (1,n,m).  Did you check to see if the `col[idx2,:]` operation makes sense?  You print `Nin` which is similar.  What's its `shape`?  Using `class1[idx]` makes sense, using it as the first index of a 2d array does not.  `col[idx,:]`.

Comment: Hi- my orginal data for class1.txt is 9061*1 matrix and for col.txt is 9061*739 matrix. Basically I want all those indices from col where the same index in class has a value 1 for Nac, and 0 for Nin. The shape of Nin is (1,158,739) where it should be (158,739). Please help!!

Comment: try `idx2 = np.where(class1==0)[0]`, so you are indexing with just the `row` values of `class1`, not both dimensions.